# FFMPEG Merge mp4 to mp4 batch

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

Hi sorry if this has already been asked but ive got intro.mp4 and over 1000 mp4 in another folder what i need is intro.mp4 to be added to every mp4 in folder im using ubuntu whats the best way to do this.

all the mp4 have the same encoding

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy output.mp4
```

this command words for one at a time 
this my attempt at batch but the var doesnt work

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "$f.ts"; done
```

this code works fine

```
 for i in *.mp4;  
do
test="concat:intro.mp4.ts|"${i%.*}".mp4.ts";
ffmpeg -i  "$test" -c copy anime2/"${i%.mp4}.mp4"; done
```

Got it working with these 2 commands did the whole batch in one script

```
 for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "$f.ts"; done


     for i in *.mp4;  
    do
    test="concat:intro.mp4.ts|"${i%.*}".mp4.ts";
    ffmpeg -i  "$test" -c copy anime2/"${i%.mp4}.mp4"; done
```

thank you

Comment: codec - yes, width - yes height- yes, pixel format -not sure, - timebase- nope audio-nope

Comment: Hi please check this paste bin https://pastebin.com/ci5ADeX2 

first 3 lines i tried worked perfectly my attempt to turn it in to batch not so much the variable doesn't seem to show no matter how i label it and at the bottom is the information you requested

Comment: 848x480 please as the 1.mp4 the main file

Comment: Please show the output of `ffprobe -v error -show_streams 1.mp4`. I should have asked for that previously instead of the `ffmpeg` output.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/X2GxNUWd 

is there no hope for my attempt at a batch?

Comment: Thanks for you help but got it working with these
   `for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts "$f.ts"; done
    
    
         for i in *.mp4;  
        do
        test="concat:intro.mp4.ts|"${i%.*}".mp4.ts";
        ffmpeg -i  "$test" -c copy anime2/"${i%.mp4}.mp4"; done`

Comment: It is possible of course, but it is not always trivial because the parameters must match. Your commands may appear to work but it will introduce unnecessary additional encoding steps and decoding oddities. For example the audio pitch will change after the intro because of the differences in audio sample rates, and there will be a difference in widthxheight and aspect which may cause distortion. Less robust players may fail. My example will not re-encode `1.mp4` and will avoid these issues.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters must match so first you must conform the intro to match the other videos (or vice versa).

Use `ffprobe` to view differences:

```
ffprove -loglevel error -show_streams intro.mp4
ffprove -loglevel error -show_streams 1.mp4
```

Re-encode `intro.mp4` to match `1.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]fps=500/21,scale=848:480:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=848:480,setsar=171/170[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -c:a aac -ar 44100 intro_b.mp4
```

Now use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat). Make a text file listing inputs to be concatenated:

```
file 'intro_b.mp4'
file '1.mp4'
```

Then concatenate:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

Comment: using your way, how would i batch it for 1000 other mp4 files i have to add it to? 

Thank you

Comment: @BenOwen You're encouraged to ask only one question per post on Stack Exchange. Yours is two questions in one: 1) how to concatenate arbitrary videos of different parameters (which this answer addresses), and 2) how to perform a batch operation. These are two very different questions. I may update this later to address both questions, but if not then I recommend editing your original question to only be about question #1, and make a new post regarding #2.